# ¿Cómo dividir un frase de manera legible en C#?

Tags: c#, .net, string

¿Cómo puedo dividir una cadena si es demasiado grande, es decir, si el número de caracteres es mayor a 25 u otro tamaño definido, pero sin que pierda legibilidad manteniendo palabras completas?.

Por ejemplo:

```
string original = "Secretaria de software y pruebas de calidad";

string[] dividido=new string[]{
    "Secretaria de software y",
    "pruebas de calidad",
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que puedes hacer es crearte un método que utilice un bucle centinela, el mismo verificara si hay mas texto por dividir.

***Dentro del bucle se evaluara:***

Si la cadena tiene menos de 25 caracteres o igual, entonces el resto de la cadena cumple con el límite de 25 y termina. Pero, si es mayor a 25, entonces se evalúa la cadena de 25 en 25 y se buscará el índice hacia atrás o último, del espacio en blanco, y entonces se substrae ese pedazo de cadena.

> Te dejo este **<kbd>[enlace](https://repl.it/@orlando722/DividirCadena01)</kbd>** para que pruebes el ejemplo de forma online.

Dejo el método **`DividirCadena`**:

```
static string[] DividirCadena(string cadena, int tamanio)
{
    List<string> cadenas = new List<string>();
    int indice = 0;
    char separador = ' ';

    string cadenaTemp = cadena.Trim();

    do
    {
        if (cadenaTemp.Length <= tamanio)
        {
            cadenas.Add(cadenaTemp.Trim());
            cadenaTemp = null;
        }
        else
        {
            indice = cadenaTemp.LastIndexOf(separador, tamanio);
            cadenas.Add(cadenaTemp.Substring(0, indice).Trim());
            cadenaTemp = cadenaTemp.Substring(indice + 1).TrimStart();
        }
    } while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cadenaTemp));

    return cadenas.ToArray();
}
```

Si estas creando una aplicación de consola, entonces en el **`Main`** llamas al método así:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string original = "Secretaria de software y pruebas de calidad";

    string[] dividido = DividirCadena(original, 25);

    foreach (string cad in dividido)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(cad);
    }
}
```

***Tener presente que el método no valida:***
- Si el parámetro `cadena` viene nula o vacía.
- Si el parámetro `tamanio` es un numero entero positivo mayor a cero.

He utilizado una lista de cadenas para mejor manipulación de cada fragmento de texto a agregar, el cual al final, termino convirtiendo en un array de cadenas.

> [Substring](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=netframework-4.8): Recupera una subcadena de la instancia. La subcadena comienza en una posición de carácter especificada y tiene una longitud especificada.
>
> [LastIndexOf](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.string.lastindexof?view=netframework-4.8#System_String_LastIndexOf_System_Char_System_Int32_): Devuelve la posición de índice de base cero de la última aparición de un carácter Unicode especificado en la instancia. La búsqueda se inicia en una posición de carácter especificada y continúa hacia atrás hacia el principio de la cadena.
>
> [List<> Class](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netframework-4.8): Representa una lista de objetos fuertemente tipados a la que se puede obtener acceso por índice. Proporciona métodos para buscar, ordenar y manipular listas.

Comment: Muchas gracias funcione awesome tnx

Answer (score 0):

puedes hacer una función que te reciba valores por parámetro.

```
public dividirCadena(cadenaADividir,separador) {
   string fraseSeparada = cadenaADividir.split(separador);
   console.write('La cadena original: ' + cadenaADividir);
   console.write("El array tiene " + fraseSeparada.length + " elementos: ");

   for (var i=0; i < fraseSeparada.length; i++) {
      console.write(fraseSeparada[i] + " / ");
   }
}
```

ya en tu **main** puedes invocar tal función por ejemplo

```
static void main(){
    string cadenaParaSeparar = "bienvenido a stackoverflow";

    string separador = " "; //indica el espacio puede ser , o . etc

    dividirCadena(cadenaParaSeparar, separador); //invocando función
}
```

Lo siento hace mucho que no toco c# tal vez tenga errores de sintaxis pero así es la lógica, el método que tu ocupas es el método split()

Suerte!

Comment: Muchas gracias, pero en generar un arreglo a partir de un string no tengo problemas

Answer (score 0):

Puedes meter todas las palabras que están separadas por espacio como te decia JL Gallardo,
y una vez que tengas solo las palabras concatenar solo la mitad de array en un string y la otra mitad en otro string, algo asi

```
static void main(){
   String original = "Secretaria de software y pruebas de calidad";
   String [] palabras = original.split(" ");
   String aux1 = "";
   String aux2 = "";

   for(int i = 0; i<(palabras.length()/2); i++) {
       aux1 += palabras[i] + " ";
   }
   for(int i = (palabras.length()/2); i<palabras.length(); i++) {
       aux2 += palabras[i] + " ";
   }

}
```